# Remove part of a div to expose underlying image

Tags: css

I have a div with a background image

```
#test {
  background-image: url('http://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-asian-developer-using-laptop-computer-sitting-working-real-office-331439570.jpg');
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

I have another child div of `test` that covers the parent `test` div

```
#cover {
  background-color: white;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">
  <div id="cover">

  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9beeeuem/)

Is it possible to manipulate the `cover` div to show a part of the image (of `test`)? For example, to show the bottom right triangle of the image while maintaining the `cover` div over the `test` div

P.S. My approach to the problem might be wrong, css is definitely not my strong suite

Comment: I'd use multiple cover elements then reduce as needed - like this https://jsfiddle.net/9beeeuem/1/

Comment: @DarrenSweeney i should have been more clear. i'm expecting text content in the cover div

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the background transparent in part with a gradient

```css
#test {
  background-image: url('http://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-asian-developer-using-laptop-computer-sitting-working-real-office-331439570.jpg');
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-size: contain;
}
#cover {
  background: linear-gradient(210deg, transparent 150px, white 150px);
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
  <div id="cover">
  
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach just by using a `borders` and you get a perfect triangle. With this you can also insert text or any other data inside the `cover` div.

```css
body{background: #111;}

#cover {

  background-color: #fff;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;

}

.triangle {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  
  background-image: url('http://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-asian-developer-using-laptop-computer-sitting-working-real-office-331439570.jpg');
  background-position: -70px -70px;
  background-size: 300px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

  display: inline-block;
  
  border: 70px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 70px solid transparent;
  border-right: 70px solid transparent;

}
```

```html
<div id="cover">
  <div class="triangle">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use css `clip-path` property. This way there is no need to use an additional html element i.e. `cover` here. Another point is that you can use **relative** dimensions instead of **absolute** ones:

```css
#test {
  background-image: url('http://image.shutterstock.com/z/stock-photo-asian-developer-using-laptop-computer-sitting-working-real-office-331439570.jpg');
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  background-size: contain;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 0 0, 100% 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="test">
</div>
```

You can use [this website](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) to create your clip path fast. Also there is a good guide on `clip-path` [here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/).

The issue is *[browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path)*.